# Issue with DAX Calculate Measure working and not working randomly

Tags: powerbi, dax, pipeline, measure

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnbHB.png)

I have a DAX measure that calculates Quote Quantity Remaining by subtracting delivered quantity from quote quantity (i.e. i quote you for 10, you buy 4, 6 are remaining)

My issue is that the measure isn't working as expected even though it should be pretty straightforward. This is the measure:

```
Quote Quantity Remaining = CALCULATE('Quote Lines by Month'[Quote Quantity by Month]-[Ticket Volume Delivered Qty])
```

I tried approaching the measure a different way as per below:

```
QtyByMonthTest = SUM('Quote Lines by Month'[MONTHLY_ORDER_QTY])-[Ticket Volume Delivered Qty]
```

When I added QtyByMonthTest, Quote Quantity Remaining began working but when I removed it, Quote Quantity Remaining broke again.

I also experienced other weird behaviors such as changing another column name in the measure fixed it, then a second column name change broke it (i.e., changed Delivered Qty to Delivered Quantity or Unit Price to Unit Price ($) ).

Further, at one point it worked in the app but then when I uploaded to our Dev pipeline it broke. I've seen the same thing happen in reverse (not work in desktop app but work in Dev pipeline) but then break from Dev to UAT to Prod.

I worked with my lead engineer and he and I are stumped, thinking it might be an issue local to my desktop.

Comment: Is `'Quote Lines by Month'[Quote Quantity by Month]` a column or a measure? If a column then your `Quote Quantity Remaining` measure isn't valid and I'm surprised you didn't get an error.

Comment: It's a measure. Our issues were resolved by reordering the customer column to be before the quote column oddly enough though we think there may be a data issue. Thanks for commenting!